# Transposing a field into fields

Tags: sql, case, teradata, transpose

I have a query that produces a 2 field result: Email and Interest.

The result is millions of records. But there are about 100 distinct Interests.

I would like to run the query to produce a result that is 101 fields wide like this:

Email | Books | Cats | Dogs | ETC

Where the metric is the count of each.

With my knowledge of SQL thus far I'd have to use CASE WHEN. But I'd have to write 100 lines of code.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the PIVOT statement but sounds like terradata does not support that. Pivot would require typing in all column names as well. Don't think you can avoid that